# Problems starting Riak TS 1.3 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

Tags: erlang, riak

I have been trying to run Riak TS 1.3.0 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4, but every time I run the start command I get this error:

```
Humbertos-MBP:bin Humberto$ ./riak start 
vm.args needs to have a -name parameter.
  -sname is not supported.
```

I tried with the rest of the commands, but the same result :(

However, I also tried on Ubunto and works perfectly

Any suggestions about my error on Mac?

Best regards,
Humberto

Comment: Humberto, did you make any changes to your Riak.conf file? I am running TS 1.3.0 on Yosemite (10.10.5) fine but I didn't make any changes to my Riak.conf file.

Comment: Hi, Craig. No I didn't do any change. I just download the .tar from basho's web site. I'm trying to run it on El capitan (10.11.4). I also tried with Riak KV and that one runs OK.

Comment: Humberto, I just installed 1.3.0 on OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan) and started it without any issues. My installation is a single node, downloaded from http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/riak_ts/1.3/1.3.0/osx/10.8/riak-ts-1.3.0-OSX-x86_64.tar.gz, unzipped to my drive, and then I did a bin/riak start without making any configuration changes.

Based on this I am guessing you made a changes to the default configuration.

Comment: Btw, I'm trying Riak TS 1.3.0 (Open Source)

Comment: Craig,  I don't know what could be the problem, I just tried with your link and I got the same error :(

Comment: Humberto, can you check your riak-ts-1.3.0/log directory to see if there is anything interesting in your error or crash logs? If you find more information in the logs please post to the original question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116192/discussion-between-humberto-and-craig).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the new version of Riak TS 1.3.1 and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing what it says... From memory `-sname` should be fine but try replacing `-sname` with `-name` in the vm.args file (will be somewhere as part of the release, just do a find on it).

**EDIT:**

According to riak documentation it should actually be riak.conf you change, it also has no mention of an `-sname` as a valid parameter. 2 things here:

1. Check you have no vm.args file overriding something
2. Change `-sname` to `-name` in your riak.conf if it exists...

http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/performance/erlang/

Comment: thanks howard, but I just updated to Riak TS 1.3.1 and it works :)